# PHP cURL not working giving me only white screen

Tags: php, curl

I am new to PHP cURL and REST API
Below is my code and i am getting plain white page with no errors.
Is I am doing it in a correct way?
If Yes please guide me the correct way of doing this.

PHP CODE

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $custMobile = $_POST['mobile_number'];
    $orderAmount = $_POST['order_amount'];
    $curl_post_data = array(
                "appId" => 'SOME ID',
                "secretKey" => 'xyz3cvb3nmLK54Jhg5654dtafnjmjjn35456657',
                "orderId" => 123456,
                "orderAmount" => $orderAmount,
                "customerPhone" => $custMobile,
                "returnUrl" => 'http://localhost/pgtest/thanks.php',
                );
        $service_url = 'MY API URL';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// set post data to true
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$curl_post_data);   // post data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    echo $obj;
    }
    ?>
```

FRONT END

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" role="form" >
            <legend>PAYEMENT GATEWAY CHECK</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Order Amount</label>
                <input type="text" name="order_amount" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Order Amount">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Mobile Number">
            </div>



            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Pay Now">
        </form>
```

Please guide me for this. Some knowledge about REST API and CURL is helpful.

Comment: Trying to output an object with `echo`... okay....

Comment: Yes, i am doing it in a correct way?

Comment: No. Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to output an object.

Comment: How will I know whether php reading the API and getting the response or not?

Comment: I used print_r($obj); than also getting blank page

Comment: add curl_error before curl_close and check what is the error?

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`  at the top of your script, what does it return ? In this case, you can also use `curl_error($ch)`

Comment: I have updated my answer for your issue, can you please try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the curl_error() method so you can find the what is the error in your reuest.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// set post data to true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$curl_post_data);   // post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

echo '<pre>';print_r($error);die;

curl_close ($ch);
```

Relating to 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' error. Rather obviously this applies to the system sending the CURL request (and no the server receiving the request)

1) Download the latest cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

2) Add the following line to php.ini (if this is shared hosting and you don't have access to php.ini then you could add this to .user.ini in public_html)

curl.cainfo=/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem

3) By default the FastCGI process will parse new files every 300 seconds (if required you can change the frequency by adding a couple of files as suggested here https://ss88.uk/blog/fast-cgi-and-user-ini-files-the-new-htaccess/)

Comment: By mistake how to remove it :(

Comment: Iam getting this message :  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate  -- What may be the problem ?

Comment: can you please these  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: before curl_exec($ch);

Comment: Disabling ssl is  a **BAD IDEA** check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30145266/797495

Comment: After putting curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); before curl_exec($ch) I am again getting white screen

Comment: @PedroLobito replace $this->ch with $ch

Comment: @PedroLobito I am getting white screen with no error

Comment: I have updated my answer for your issue, can you please try that?

Comment: Thank you Harsh, It works for me.. thanks a lot saved lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

I had manually set up a server on my Windows. I was trying to upload images to dropbox by "token" access, and was not succeeding.

I did the following:

1. I downloaded the "cacert.pem";
2. put the file in "c:/server/ssl" (folder I made up);
3. I went to php.ini and opened it with sublime text;
4. I searched for "curl.cainfo" by giving [ctrl + f];
5. I unchecked the line and pointed to the file path;
6. Then I restarted the server and it worked;

Feel free to choose the folder where you want to put this file. Pointing to the right path is what matters.

[Download cacert.pem](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html)